# Delaying CreateJS Animation Timeline

Tags: javascript, flash, animation, delay, createjs

I'd been using Swiffy to output .fla files pretty easily, but then I was tipped off that the display would alternate "flashing" white over half the project if viewed in Landscape Mode on a iPad. Very strange behavior, which I couldn't replicate on any other device.

So, I've moved on to trying to use CreateJS to fix the issue. I only know enough JS at this time to get by editing code developed by others, so I've been very ineffective so far.

I've gotten this far:

```
/* js
this.stop();
var t=setTimeout(function(){(this.play())}, 1000);
*/

or

/* js
this.stop();
setTimeout(this.play(), 1000);
*/
```

I've not been able to get the animation to mind the timeout, and I've tried MANY different variants to try and make some magic happen. All it does is immediately loads the next frame, it doesn't pause at all. Where am I going wrong here?

Here is the original Actionscript:

```
stop();

var shortTimer:Timer=new Timer(1000); 
shortTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerN1); 
shortTimer.start(); 


function timerN1(e:TimerEvent):void{ 
    play(); 
    shortTimer.reset(); 
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated, as I've gotten no where on my own trying to fix this is in my off time for several weeks, and my client is becoming increasingly angry. More of a designer, still very uneducated as far as programming is concerned. Again, even a suggestion would be super helpful at this point. Can't seem to crack it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is more correct:

```
/* js
this.stop();
var t=setTimeout(function(){(this.play())}, 1000);
*/
```

However, you may find that "this" is Window, not the MovieClip that calls it. You can get around this by using a local reference (in this case, its "_this").

```
/* js
this.stop();
var _this = this;
var t=setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(this, _this);
    _this.play();
}, 1000);
*/
```

You can test this by looking at your console, and seeing what the difference between "this" and "_this" is.

Cheers.

Comment: This worked! Thank you SO much! One edit though, you left out the "n" in "function". CHEERS!

Answer (score 0):

Could you possibly post more of the code you are working with? Have you tried using the onAnimationEnd function:

```
var _this = this;

_this.onAnimationEnd = function() {
    _this.stop();
    setTimeout(function(){
       _this.play();
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, possibly because I have nothing named "animation"? Thank you for your input!

Comment: Well, I could possibly help more if I could see more of your code (the javascript creating the animation). I use CreateJS quite frequently

Comment: This has the same issue as the original, where function scope has been compromised.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to keep your scope alive inside your `setTimeout` function :

```
sprite.on('animationend', function(event) {
    event.target.stop();
    setTimeout(animationend.bind(event.target), 1000);
});

function animationend() {
    this.gotoAndPlay('run');
}
```

With the use of `.bind()` you can pass an object as the scope in the called function. [More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind).